# Fourier transform of certain noisy function

Tags: fourier-transform, noise

So, I have a noisy signal in time domain, $f(t) = t \eta(t)$ where $\eta(t)$ is white noise with variance $\sigma$ and mean zero, and that it has the property $\langle \eta(t)\eta(t') \rangle = \sigma^2 \delta(t-t')$ ($\langle \ldots \rangle$ denotes ensemble averaging). What I want to do is that I want to calculate the square magnitude of the spectrum in frequency domain upon ensemble averaging, $\langle |z(\omega)|^2 \rangle$. To do this, I follow Dave's answer in https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/53739/magnitude-of-the-fourier-transform-of-white-noise. So, it will be
$$
\langle |z(\omega)|^2 \rangle = \iint e^{i\omega t} e^{-i\omega t'}t't \langle \eta(t)\eta(t') \rangle dt dt'
$$
Using the property stated above, $\langle \eta(t)\eta(t') \rangle = \sigma^2 \delta(t-t')$, I can obtain
$$
\langle |z(\omega)|^2 \rangle = \sigma^2 \int t^2 dt
$$.
Thus, the ensemble averaged square magnitude of my function is independent of $\omega$.

Now I perform the same calculation using MATLAB and I obtained the following pictures.
[image]

It seems like when I take ensemble average of the lower curve, it will be dependent on $\omega$, which contradicts my calculation. Can someone please point out my mistake(s)?

```
clear all;
clc;

n = 2048;
ft = rand(1,n)*(2+2)-2 + 0;
t = linspace(-10,10,n);
Dt = 1/(t(3)-t(1));

fw = ifft(fft(t.*ft));
w = (-length(t)/2:length(t)/2-1)*2*pi*Dt/length(t);
subplot(211)
plot(t,t.*ft)
xlabel('t')
ylabel('f(t)')

subplot(212)
plot(w,abs(fw).^2)
xlabel('\omega')
ylabel('|z(\omega)|^2')
```

That's my code. By the way I think you are using normal distribution for the noise, I used white noise type.

Comment: You are taking the FT of $t\eta(t)$, not of $\eta(t)$.  That factor of $t$ definitely makes the FT dependent on frequency, even if $\eta$ does not.  In fact, I would say you are getting the exact result you should be getting.

Comment: Of course the FT of $t\eta(t)$ (and also $\eta(t)$ alone) will depend on $\omega$. But what I calculate is the ensemble average of the squared magnitude of the spectrum which, according to my possibly wrong calculation, does not depend on frequency.

Comment: Just wondering: You seem to have moved on from this question.  Did my answer get you what you needed? If so, please accept it as the answer (click the check mark / tick beside it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, this line looks odd:

```
fw = ifft(fft(t.*ft));
```

Why are you immediately taking the inverse FFT?  Surely you just want:

```
fw = abs(fft(t.*ft));
```

???

---

This is not really an answer, more a request for more information.

I try to repeat your example in `R` and I cannot get the FFT you get.  What I get is plotted below.  Can you share your matlab code? I'm wondering what it's doing.

[image]

---

**R Code Below**

```
#27432

T2 <- 1000

f <- rnorm(2*T2+1) * seq(-T,T,1)

par(mfrow=c(2,1))
plot(f, type="l", col="blue")
plot(abs(fft(f)), type="l", col="blue")
```

Comment: I know my previous answer is not an answer but I want to respond to your answer by sharing my code as you requested. Can I write a code in a comment?
By the way, yeah you are write. That ifft should have been ifftshift, my bad.

Comment: @nougako: I've edited your question and added it there.  Have a look at my updated answer.

Comment: By the way, I think the ensemble average of my $f(t)$ is approximately equal to the time average. Based on this, can I say that $f(t)$ is an ergodic signal?

Comment: @nougako : I'm uncertain if $f(t)$ is ergodic, because of the time dependence on the variance.

Answer (score 1):

After thinking more about this, I am pretty sure that what you really want to do, and what your MATLAB probably in fact is doing, is study the a function like

$\displaystyle f(t)=\int^tdt^\prime (t-t^\prime)\eta(t^\prime)$

with $\eta(t)$ having the correlation property you've already mentioned.  This will give an FT that is definitely frequency dependent and, I think, looking like your MATLAB results.